# Espresso tests do not update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have a problem with **Espresso**.

The test work fine but whenever I change the something in the test and run them : **The tests are not updating**.

Basically the "old" version of the tests run.
To force the test to update I use the Gradle task : **uninstallAll**

Here is my config :

1. **Test**

   ```
   package com.shockn745.moovin5.main;

   import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
   import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
   import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

   import com.shockn745.moovin5.R;

   import org.junit.Before;
   import org.junit.Rule;
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

   import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
   import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
   import static org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf;

   /**
    * UI Test for the Main Screen
    */
   @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
   @LargeTest
   public class MainScreenTest {

       private final static String WRONG_DURATION = "asdssssssssf";
       private final static String RIGHT_DURATION = "40";

       @Rule
       public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
               new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

       @Before
       public void initTest() {
           // Do nothing for now
       }

       @Test
       public void enterDuration_success() {
           // Type text and then press the button.
           onView(withId(R.id.main_edit_text))
                   .perform(typeText(RIGHT_DURATION), closeSoftKeyboard());
           onView(withId(R.id.main_button)).perform(click());

           // Check that Motivation Activity is displayed
           onView(withId(R.id.motivation_toolbar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
       }

       @Test
       public void enterDuration_parse_error() {
           // Type text and then press the button.
           onView(withId(R.id.main_edit_text))
                   .perform(typeText(WRONG_DURATION), closeSoftKeyboard());
           onView(withId(R.id.main_button)).perform(click());

           // Check that the text was changed.
           onView(allOf(
                   withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text),
                   withText(R.string.main_error_snackbar)
           )).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
       }

       @Test
       public void enterDuration_empty_error() {
           // Press the button. with no text
           onView(withId(R.id.main_button)).perform(click());

           // Check that the text was changed.
           onView(allOf(
                   withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text),
                   withText(R.string.main_error_snackbar)
           )).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Gradle**

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.shockn745.moovin5"
           minSdkVersion 16
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"

           testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   /*
   Resolves dependency versions across test and production APKs, specifically, transitive
   dependencies. This is required since Espresso internally has a dependency on support-annotations.
   */
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
           force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

       // Android libraries
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

       // Google libraries
       compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

       // Network operations
       compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

       // Unit testing
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
       testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"

       // UI testing
       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
       androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1"
       androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1"

       // External libraries
       compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
   }
   ```
3. **Run config**

[image: Run config]

Any ideas ?

Thank you so much if you can find a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Please go to `Edit Configurations` -> `Main Screen Test` -> `Miscellaneous` -> And disable `Skip installation if apk has not changed`

Answer (score 1):

I had to uncheck "Skip installation if APK has not changed" for not only the test configuration but the app configuration as well

[image]